# Showing an isomorphism between Hom sets

Tags: category-theory

I am trying to show that if $(F,G,\eta,\epsilon)$ is the data of an equivalence of categories $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$, then $Hom_\mathcal{C}(x,y)$ and $Hom_\mathcal{C} (GF(x),GF(y))$ are isomorphic.

I have managed to show that it is injective, but I am struggling to show it is surjective. Could anyone provide a hint in the right direction?

Comment: I would probably just explicitly write the pair of inverse maps between those sets, and then verify they are indeed inverses.

Comment: And by "isomorphic", do you mean just that the sets are bijective for any particular $x,y$, or that the two functors $\mathcal{C}^{op} \times \mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{Sets}$ are isomorphic functors?

Comment: We already have $\hom_{\mathcal C}(x,y) \cong \hom_{\mathcal D}(F(x),\,F(y))$ since $F$ is an equivalence functor. Now apply it again with $G$